# How does the exclamantion mark work in symfony configuration files?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, yaml

Take this as an example: https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/master/src/Akeneo/Platform/Bundle/UIBundle/Resources/config/services.yml#L84

```
Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\UIBundle\Provider\ExternalJavascriptDependenciesProvider:
    arguments:
        - !tagged akeneo.pim.security.external_dependency_provider
```

And this: https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/master/src/Akeneo/Platform/Bundle/UIBundle/Provider/ExternalJavascriptDependenciesProvider.php

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\UIBundle\Provider;

final class ExternalJavascriptDependenciesProvider
{
    private iterable $externalDependenciesProviders;

    public function __construct(iterable $externalDependenciesProviders)
    {
        $this->externalDependenciesProviders = $externalDependenciesProviders;
    }

    public function getScripts(): array
    {
        $dependencies = [];

        foreach ($this->externalDependenciesProviders as $externalDependenciesProvider) {
            $dependencies[] = $externalDependenciesProvider->getScript();
        }

        return $dependencies;
    }
}
```

Because the constructor accepts an iterable as argument, I understand it must be an array with all services tagged as `akeneo.pim.security.external_dependency_provider`, but I can't find documentation about it anywhere.
I could find some documentation about `!tagged_iterator` here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#tagged-services-with-index but it doesn't mention just "!tagged" (without the _iterator suffix)

Answer (score -1):

`!tagged` and `!tagged_iterator` are the same. It's just that the former got renamed to the latter.

See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31289